Confusion with queries on UniProt
New to the UniProt API and RestAPIs in general, so I'm really confused why 3 seemingly identical queries yield a different number of results.
1: https://www.uniprot.org/uniref/UniRef90_P01009
yields 88 results
2: https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb?query=%28uniref_cluster_90%3AUniRef90_P01009%29
yields 49 results
3: https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/search?query=(uniref_cluster_90:UniRef90_P01009)
yields 28 results
Could anyone help explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
